# How to find a value in columns and return the column name in Python

Tags: python, pandas, max

I have the following pivot table, with the last column returning the max value of the row.

```
            totalCount                          max
hours           0   1   2   3   ... 21  22  23  
    username                                                                                    
    user_1      3   0   0   5   ... 0   0   1   5
    user_2      0   0   6   0   ... 2   4   0   6   
    user_3      5   0   0   3   ... 0   0   1   5
    user_4      0   2   3   0   ... 0   8   0   8
    user_5      1   4   0   0   ... 5   9   2   9
```

Now I want to add another column 'hour' that returns the name of the column where the max value belongs.

The **output** would be the following:

```
            totalCount                          max hour
hours           0   1   2   3   ... 21  22  23  
    username                                                                                    
    user_1      3   0   0   5   ... 0   0   1   5   3
    user_2      0   0   6   0   ... 2   4   0   6   2
    user_3      5   0   0   3   ... 0   0   1   5   0
    user_4      0   2   3   0   ... 0   8   0   8   22
    user_5      1   4   0   0   ... 5   9   2   9   22
```

Any idea on how to create this column that finds the column name?

And what if the max value is repeated in various columns? I guess I would be returned the name of the first column that has that value, but would be any code to get all the column names where this max value appears? *(This is an extra question that I appreciate if you can answer, but the main question is the previous one).*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.idxmax()` which returns the index of the max element coupled with `.apply` on `axis=1`:

```
df['where_max'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.idxmax(), axis=1)
```

Minimal Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'x': [1, 3, 4, 7], 'wave': [2, 2, 10, 0], 'y': [0,0,0,15]})
df['where_max'] = df.apply(lambda x : x.idxmax(), axis=1)

    x   wave    y   where_max
0   1   2       0   wave
1   3   2       0   x
2   4   10      0   wave
3   7   0       15  y
```

Comment: Thanks. It works in your case, but in mine, instead of getting only the value in the column `where_max` I'm getting for example this: `(totalCount, 19)`. How could I get only the value of `19` as in your case?

Comment: I guess that is because you have a MultiLevelIndex. You can easily slice it `.apply(lambda x: x.idxmax()[1], axis=1)`

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!